# How do I prevent my keyboard from trying to suggest 2 sets of spelling corrections?

Tags: keyboard

A decent while ago, my keyboard decided to start recommending two sets of spelling corrections. The new type of spelling corrections tends to get in the way of me using the one that I prefer to use.

For reference, I included an image. The popup coming down from the misspelled word is the spelling correction system I do not want to use, while the one underneath it is the one I do want to use.

I am on an LG phone with Android version 9.

[image: Reference Image]

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after asking the question I decided to do some testing, and I figured out how to fix it. I went into my keyboard settings and disabled the spelling correction feature. This disabled only the "red line with drop down" spelling correction set while the spelling correction set that was below it and built into the keyboard was still there.

It was under Settings > General > Language & keyboard > Spelling correction. From there, I disabled it, and everything was back to how I liked it.